# How to wait for meta-tag "user-scalable=no" being ready on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, mobile

I noticed a strange behaviour on my HTC One Android Phone with mobile Firefox:

In the HTML-Header I set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But it seems like it takes a little time before this option really applies.
I call the following code on $(document).ready(…) :

```
alert($(document.body).width());
setTimeout(function(){
    alert($(document.body).width());
},1000);
```

Now, the first and second alert-box show different widths! The first one is greater and corresponds to the width as if i had not set the meta tag – the second one is finally the correct width.

When I call the code at body.onload="…" instead, both alerts show the same value.

Is this a bug? Or is there a way to prevent this delay?

Comment: Try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />1

With `;` and not `,`

Comment: Amazing! the "1" solves the problem - actually it seems that any character (that is not whitespace) RIGHT AFTER the meta tag solves it - I will go with <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">&nbsp; – Thank you Sagar Pilkhwal! I would upvote your answer if it weren't just a comment - Do you have any idea why this works?

Comment: so shall i post the above comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />1
```

With `;` and not `,`

Comment: you forgot the essential "1"

Comment: it was a very lucky typo - i first left it out - it didn't work - i then added it - and it worked - then i added the closing /> (which i forgot first) and it didn't work again

Comment: Thanks again! I am testing it over and over again right now and it's really not the ";" nor the "target-densityDpi=device-dpi" - there has to be a non-whitespace-character right after the meta-tag (later doesn't work) - this is strange and i never heard of it but i suppose the character triggers some form of rendering or something BEFORE document.ready() gets called

Comment: Lets just say that Typo was very lucky :)